# how to convert a column with string datetime to datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i want to convert a column with string date '19 Desember 2022' for example (the month name is in Indonesian), to supported datetime format without translating it, how do i do that?

already tried this one
 `df_train['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_train['date'], format='%d %B %Y')` but got error `time data '19 Desember 2022' does not match format '%d %B %Y' (match)`

incase if anyone want to see the [row image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5f7Z.png)

Comment: it should be `December` instead of `Desember` in your data

Comment: no in bahasa(indonesian language) Desember is December, thats what am asking for, how to make it datetime format without have to translate it to english

Comment: then replace in your data replace Desember to December then apply time formate

Answer (score 1):

Try using [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

```py
import dateparser
df_train = pd.DataFrame(['19 Desember 2022', '20 Desember 2022', '21 Desember 2022', '22 Desember 2022'], columns = ['date'])
df_train['date'] = [dateparser.parse(x) for x in df_train['date']]
df_train
```

Output:

```
    date
0   2022-12-19
1   2022-12-20
2   2022-12-21
3   2022-12-22
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas doesn't recognize bahasa(indonesian language) Try replacing the spelling of December (as pointed out you can use a one liner and create a new column):

```
df_train["formatted_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_train["date"].str.replace("Desember", "December"), format="%d %B %Y")
print(df_train)
```

Output:

```
  user_type              date formatted_date
0   Anggota  19 Desember 2022     2022-12-19
1   Anggota  19 Desember 2022     2022-12-19
2   Anggota  19 Desember 2022     2022-12-19
3   Anggota  19 Desember 2022     2022-12-19
4   Anggota  19 Desember 2022     2022-12-19
```

Comment: Or just as a one-liner: `df_train['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_train['date'].str.replace('Desember', 'December'), format='%d %B %Y')`

Comment: is there anyway to keep the month "Desember" ? id like to keep it in Indonesian without have to translate the month format

Comment: no I don't think you can

Comment: Add a new column with the replace